# SFTP user login details real-time filtering

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, mysql, syslog

I have enabled the SFTP login log into the default logfile `/var/log/syslog` and tried to filter the login time of each user and insert into the database.

But the filtering is not worked as I expected.

Sample log file:

```
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24938]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24938]: Starting Exit the Session..c.
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24938]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 24980 (kill).
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1051.
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of nidasu.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of ftpuser1.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1069...
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Started Session 11907571 of user ftpuser1.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Paths.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Timers.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Sockets.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Basic System.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Default.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Startup finished in 15ms.
```

Needs to filter user login messages, like:

```
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Started Session 11907571 of user ftpuser1.
```

I need to grep it out by matching the string "Started Session `11907571` of user `ftpuser1`"

The session number `11907571` is a random number and usernames also differ so grepping can ignore the numbers and usernames, only need to check the string like: **"Started Session *** of user *****"**

And need to parse the line and `grep` the `date + time`, and username then insert it into the MySQL database.

If there is any option to create a daemon process to run and insert the details into DB, it will help me to do the task.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of solution in [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr).

```
(defvarl db-user "user")
(defvarl db-pw "password")

(defun mysql-insert (db-name table-name . values)
  (let* ((alist (plist-to-alist values))
         (columns [mapcar car alist])
         (values [mapcar cdr alist]))
    ;; fix as necessary, remove echo
    (sh `echo mysql -u @{db-user} -p@{db-pw} -e \ \
         "INSERT INTO @{db-name}.${table-name} (@{columns ", "}) \ \
          VALUES ('@{values "', '"}')"`)))

;; (daemon nil nil) ;; uncomment to daemonize

(let ((log (open-tail "syslog")))
  (whilet ((line (get-line log)))
    (if-match `@mon @day @hh:@mm:@ss @nil systemd[@pid]: Started Session @num of user @user.` line
      (mysql-insert "log-db" "sftp-table"
                    'date `@mon @day @hh:@mm:@ss`
                    'user user))))
```

When I run this on the data, it scans the log and prints the MySQL command:

```
$ txr daemon.tl
mysql -u user -ppassword -e INSERT INTO log-db.name (date, user)  VALUES ('Jun 23 15:47:13', 'ftpuser1')
```

Then, it waits for more data to be added to the log. The stream opened by `open-tail` works like `tail -f` on a log file.  It will automatically detect when the file has been rotated, and works even when files are rotated by renaming. If `syslog` is renamed to `syslog.1` and a new `syslog` file starts being written, it will follow.

Speaking of `syslog`, obviously this needs to be pointed to the real file also, in addition to the other edits to make it work, like massaging the date into the desired format, using the real database, table and column names and so on.

The database password could come in via an environment variable or command line argument. Though if this is run as a daemon, it will have to be recorded *somewhere*.

The `values` being inserted into the database command have to be properly escaped; what if the user name contains `'` for whatever reason.